# mintty: how to keep my output visible after processes terminate?

Tags: cygwin, mintty

I have a desktop shortcut that starts a cygwin bash script and I want the mintty terminal to stay open after my script terminates so that I can look at it's output. For this purpose I'm using the `-h always` mintty option[1].

The window does stay open but the output is unhelpfully cleared by mintty just as my script terminates(!!!). Seems like a bad joke. Am I missing something? I've verified this behavior even with a one line script with just an echo.

---

**Note** [1] `-h` is described like this in the man page:

```
-h, --hold never|start|error|always

Determine whether to keep the terminal window open when the command has finished and no more processes are connected to the terminal.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was running my script with `bash --login` so on termination it implicitly calls `/etc/bash.bash_logout` which includes a line that runs `/usr/bin/clear` (*"to increase privacy"*).

---

**Credits**: I found the answer [in this bug report](https://github.com/mintty/mintty/issues/255#issuecomment-108889932) which includes this helpful explanation:

```
>  Hmm, the screen clearing is done by the latest /etc/bash.bash_logout:

# when leaving the console clear the screen to increase privacy   if
[ "$SHLVL" = 1 ]; then
    [ -x /usr/bin/clear ] && /usr/bin/clear   
fi
```

Answer (score 5):

I ran a few tests, and the `-h always` mintty option worked as expected; the screen did not get cleared and the window stayed open.

Here is the exact shortcut "Target" I used for running a script:

```
C:\cygwin64\bin\mintty.exe -h always /usr/bin/bash -l ~/helloworld.bash
```

I am using mintty 2.7.7 (x86_64-pc-cygwin).

Hopefully, upgrading mintty and/or using the syntax as shown above will fix things for you.  If not, you could force a pause within the script itself by adding a `read` command like so:

```
echo 'Script end.  Press ENTER to close'
read
```

Comment: I was using exactly the same options with mintty 2.7.9 (x86_64-pc-cygwin) so it must be a bug. Thanks for your time Michael.